# Fazer logout e atualizar página

Tags: php

Estou editando um painel de usuário, com login entre outros.
Mas tenho uma dúvida, quando clico em SAIR (o logout da página), precisaria que ele atualizasse a página além de sair da conta de usuário, já tentei incrementar diversos codigos de refresh e reload mas nenhum funcionou

Este é o codigo que aparece na index

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="loading(\'?go=painel&deslogar=true\', \'painel\');">SAIR</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Este é o codigo

```
    if($_GET["deslogar"] == true) {
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ?go=painel&painel=true;");
}
```

Comment: Coloque um ./ antes do endereço de redirecionamento. Exemplo: ./?go=painel*painel=true, ou informe o endereço completo de redirecionamento, incluindo o protocolo http ou https.

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo assim:

```
<a href='session_destroy.php'>Sair</a>
```

E na página da session destroy coloque o valor que você está comparando como string:

```
if($_GET["deslogar"] == "true") {
    session_destroy();
    header("location: caminho/para/minha/outra/pagina.php;");
}
```

creio que o true sem as aspas está sendo entendido como 1 porque o php deriva de C e em C não existe o tipo booleano (true e false),  apenas int (1 e 0). Quando você pega um agrumeto via GET ele é uma string. Portanto você está comparando uma string "true" com um int 1.